# Rebase into a subtree

Tags: git, git-subtree

The situation is that we have two repositories, `parent` and `child`.
The `parent` repo has the `child` repo as a subtree:

```
parent/
  child/
```

After some time, the `child` repository has diverged from its upstream (patches have been made for use of the `parent` project, which have not been contributed to `child`'s upstream).

What is the right Git command to extract a patch from the `child` subtree (and only that specific patch) so it can be upstreamed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, let's name the following branches:

- `main` is the main branch of the `parent` repository (includes the patches that we don't want to upstream, but excludes the patches that we do want to upstream),
- `feature` is the branch in which the patches that we want to upstream are; `feature` is based on `main`
- `child-main` is the main branch of the `child` upstream (where we want to send our patches to)

We want to create the `child-feature` branch, which contains all the modifications strictly in the `feature` branch without anything from `main`.

We can do so like this:

```bash
git switch -b child-feature feature
git rebase -i -s subtree --onto child-main main
```

Explanation:

- `git switch feature`: switches to the `feature` branch

  - `-b child-feature`: creates the `child-feature` branch on top of the `feature` branch
- `git rebase`: moves the current branch by copying all commits it contains

  - `-i`: interactive, not necessary but convenient to understand what is happening
  - `-s subtree`: use the `subtree` strategy, which knows how to deal with subtrees (all changes to the parent repository are removed, and all changes are 'moved' so the project root is the subtree directory)
  - `--onto child-main`: place the results on top of the `child-main` branch
  - `main`: only take into account changes that were made after the commit `main` points to (ignores previous patches)